# What is Codepage 0?

Tags: delphi, unicode, character-encoding, delphi-2009, codepages

I'm using the Delphi function

```
StringCodePage
```

I call it on a string returned by a COM function (Acrobat Annotation getContents - see my other posts) and it returns 0.

What is 0? Ansi?

Comment: It might also be useful to know that you can change it (without reinstall): http://www.mihai-nita.net/article.php?artID=20050611a

Comment: The only way `StringCodePage()` can return 0 is if you are passing a blank `AnsiString` to it, or a non-blank `AnsiString` with codepage 0 in its payload. Delphi uses `WideString` for COM strings. In D2009, the RTL did not do a very good job of storing actual codepage values into `AnsiString` payloads so it commonly had 0, as that is the compile-time codepage affinity, not the run-time affinity. That was fixed in later Delphi versions.

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code page 0 is CP_ACP, current Windows ANSI code page.

From Windows.pas:

```
{$EXTERNALSYM CP_ACP}
CP_ACP                   = 0;             { default to ANSI code page }
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776413.aspx):

> CP_ACP
>
> The current system Windows ANSI code page. This value can be different on different
> computers, even on the same network. It can be changed on the same computer, leading to
> stored data becoming irrecoverably corrupted. This value is only intended for temporary
> use and permanent storage should be done using UTF-16 or UTF-8 if possible.

Answer (score 4):

The only way `StringCodePage()` can return 0 is if you are passing in a blank `AnsiString`, thus returning its compile-time codepage affinity, or are passing in a non-blank `AnsiString` that has codepage 0 assigned to its payload.  Delphi uses `WideString` for COM strings, and `StringCodePage()` will not return 0 for any string type except plain `AnsiString`.  In D2009, the RTL did not do a very good job of storing the OS's actual run-time codepage into `AnsiString` payloads, so they commonly contained the compile-time codepage affinity of 0.  That is functional in regards to string conversions, but it not very explicit. That was fixed in later Delphi versions so `AnsiString` payloads now contain the actual OS codepage that is determined at run-time.